# How to open a Kendo window at mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

Is there a way to open a Kendo UI Window at the mouse pointer?

I can see in the [Telerik demo for the Window API](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/window/api), that I can open it on center of the page, but I want to open it at the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, keep the current mouse position stored somewhere:

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
});
```

Then, when opening your Kendo Window:

```
$("#window").closest(".k-window").css({
    top: currentMousePos.y,
    left: currentMousePos.x
});
```

Comment: Works great! Since I joined stackoverflow just recently I do not have enough reputation to vote up your answer, but take my +1